# Making a button that loads into a loaded swf file and unloads the swf on click

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am doing a portfolio type project and am having trouble creating a button that appears in my loaded swf files.  I am very new to flash.  The portfolio has 2 projects that get loaded when they are clicked.  I need to also have a button that appears when they are click as well.

Right now I have it set to unload on click again but that doesn't work because one of the projects is interactive.  My code so far is

```
var myLoader:Loader=new Loader ();
project2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, project2content); 
function project2content(myevent:MouseEvent):void {
    var myURL:URLRequest=new URLRequest("Project2.swf"); 
    myLoader.load(myURL); 
    addChild(myLoader);
}

project3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, project3content); 
function project3content(myevent:MouseEvent):void {
    var myURL:URLRequest=new URLRequest("Project3.swf"); 
    myLoader.load(myURL); 
    addChild(myLoader);
}

myLoader.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, unloadcontent); 
function unloadcontent(myevent:MouseEvent):void {
    removeChild(myLoader);
    project2.gotoAndPlay(1); 
    project3.gotoAndPlay(1); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to be able to add a close button to one or both of your project SWFs and have your parent movie pick up clicks on those buttons.

If so, try creating a button in your project SWFs and including the following code:

```
closeButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, closeHandler);
function closeHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    dispatchEvent(new Event("close"));
}
```

And replace the code which is related to the click event on myLoader with the following:

```
myLoader.content.addEventListener("close", closeHandler);
function closeHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
    removeChild(myLoader);
    project2.gotoAndPlay(1); 
    project3.gotoAndPlay(1); 
}
```